# How to calculate current time in different timezone correctly in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, dst, pytz

I was trying to calculate the current time in NYC (EST time aka Eastern Daylight time or  GMT-4) given current time in Israel (Israel daylight time, currently GMT+3) where I'm currently located. So right now Israel is  7 hrs ahead of NYC, but I get an 8 hr difference, with NYC coming out an hour earlier than it really is:

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime
tz1 = timezone('Israel')
dt1 = datetime.now(tz1)
tz2 = timezone('EST')
dt2 = datetime.now(tz2)
print(f'{dt1}  vs  {dt2} ')

output: 2023-05-24 17:01:47.167155+03:00  vs  2023-05-24 09:01:47.167219-05:00
```

Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was trying to calculate the current time in NYC (EST time aka Eastern Daylight time or GMT+4)

This is where your problem lies - assuming that "EST" means "Eastern Daylight Time". It doesn't. It *always* means Eastern *Standard* Time (at least in the context of the US; ideally it's better to avoid using the abbreviations entirely), which is UTC-5. (As an aside, I'd strongly advise you never to refer to "GMT+4" like that. I know that's what the Posix Etc/GMT+4 etc means, but it's very, very confusing due to being backwards to basically everything else.)

The New York time zone varies between EST and EDT (UTC-5 and UTC-4). So if that's what you mean, say so:

```py
tz2 = timezone('America/New_York')
```

I'd also suggest using `Asia/Jerusalem` instead of `Israel` as your source time zone - use [identifiers from IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). So then we have complete code of:

```py
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime
tz1 = timezone('Asia/Jerusalem')
dt1 = datetime.now(tz1)
tz2 = timezone('America/New_York')
dt2 = datetime.now(tz2)
print(f'{dt1}  vs  {dt2} ')
```

Output:

```
2023-05-24 17:43:31.121887+03:00  vs  2023-05-24 10:43:31.122888-04:00
```

Comment: thanks for this - as for 'gmt+-x' that's how calendar times are displayed in google calendar iirc which is where I think i picked up that lingo - when you say its backwards to everything else do you mean times relative to utc are always given as negative numbers?

Comment: @jeremy_rutman: No, Google Calendar shows the correct offset, at least in the time zone settings for a calendar entry, e.g. "(GMT-04:00) Eastern Time - New York". There are Posix time zone IDs of (say) "Etc/GMT+5" which actually means UTC-5... but those should definitely be avoided. I'm not sure where you saw New York as "GMT+4" but that's basically incorrect.

Comment: side note, pytz is outdated since Python 3.9. Since then, there's [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) in the standard library.

Comment: @FObersteiner: That's what I get for answering Python questions ;)

Comment: no worries, just wanted to leave a hint here. pytz is still a pretty wide-spread dependency, so OP might *have* to use it for some reason.

Comment: the gmt+-x reference abt google wasn't about the specific value but rather their use of gmt instead of utc

Comment: @jeremy_rutman: But the point is that the direction is "wrong". I've only *ever* seen the US have a GMT+x value (as opposed to GMT-x) when using the old Posix-style time zone IDs. Where have you seen Google calendar refer to New York as "GMT+4" or "GMT+5"? Note that by the way you've written your question, it sounds like you believe Israel and New York are only an hour apart: "(EST time aka Eastern Daylight time or GMT+4)" and "(Israel daylight time, currently GMT+3)".

Comment: again my question didn't concern the specific value but rather whether you meant using GMT+-x isn't best practice

Comment: @jeremy_rutman: Using UTC is generally preferred over GMT, but I *still* don't know where you've *ever* seen New York described as GMT+4. *You* may not be interested in that specific value, but you included it in your question, and *I'm* interested in where you saw it.

Comment: it was - not +, mistake in orig. question correct.     google searches for timezones seem to regularly report timezones using GMT, not UTC